# Sound recorded but not playing in iOS

Tags: swift, playback

In an iOS app, I record a sound (.caf): I can see the file is in the Documents directory and I can drag it from iTunes to my desktop and play it (it contains what I record).

I test this thing on a regular device and when I play the sound I can't hear any sound: the device volume is at its maximum.

The code I use to play the sound is the following and returns no error:

```
let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

let fullPath = (documentsDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("docu.caf")

let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(fullPath)

do {
   let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
   // sound is printed as <AVAudioPlayer: 0x14ed5bd20>
   print(sound)
   sound.prepareToPlay()
   sound.play()
  } catch {
   // never gets called
   print("couldn't load any file")
}
```

Any idea is appreciated...

Comment: `AVAudioPlayer ` instance needs a strong reference  or it will release

Comment: @WilsonXJ Ok, I converted AVAudioPlayer to a member and now it works. Please, could you point me to a resource where I can read something related to your reply? Why a member works and a local variable not? I've seen dozen of samples with local variables...

Comment: you can google the keyword "ARC" 、 "Automatic Reference Counting" or search it in StackOverflow